# Подстановка числа к названию функции

Tags: php

Есть 2 функции func_1 и func_2.
Как к названию функции подставить случайное число

```
 $rand = rand(1,2);
```

чтобы получилось

```
echo func_случайное_число ();
```

Я хотел сделать следующее

```
$homescore = "1";
$awayscore = "0";

function func_1() {
 echo $hometeam ." дома с минимальным преимуществом переиграл " . $awayteam; 
}
function func_2() {
 echo $awayteam ." на выезде минимально проиграл " . $hometeam; 
}
$rand = rand(1,2);

if ($homescore > $awayscore) {
 $scoredif = $homescore - $awayscore;
  switch ($scoredif) {
   case 1: //Минимальная победа хозяев
    $random_function = "func_{$rand}";
    echo $random_function();
   break;
  }
}
```

Суть всего этого вывод новостного заголовка о фубольном матче. Если матч закончился победой хозяев поля то применяется один из шаблонов:

```
Хозяева победили дома Гостей
Гости проиграли на выезде Хозяевам
```

Comment: А зачем такие [извращения](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)? У вас серьёзные просчёты в архитектуре вашего приложения.

Comment: @romeo , а разве можно избавиться от извращений в коде не пройдя через них!?)

Comment: Чё уж там, давайте до конца: `$function_name = "test_{$_POST['malware']}"; echo $function_name();`

Comment: Вы лучше напишите зачем вам это надо, может подскажут правильное решени, т.к. ваш путь ошибочен

Comment: @EugeneMoskvin именно для того от них и избавляются, чтобы не проходить через них.

Comment: @Eugene Moskvin: `выглядит извращение крайней степени` Именно. Стоит подумать, как решить вашу задачу другим способом. Имена функций, а для ООП методов и свойств объекта должны указываться явно, а не с помощью вычислений (ваш случай), и тем более подстановкой переменных с данными извне.

Comment: @korytoff я описал что хочу сделать

Comment: Я обновил свой ответ под ваши условия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит обратить внимание на вот эту статью в документации:
**[Обращение к функциям через переменные](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.variable-functions.php)**

Вот пример реализации:

```
$rand = rand(1, 2);

function test_1 () {
    return 'test 1';
}

function test_2 () {
    return 'test 2';
}

$random_function = "test_{$rand}";

echo $random_function();
```

---

Eugene Moskvin, к сожалению, из вашего вопроса мне не представляется возможным понять какая задача стояла перед вами изначально, а следовательно ответить я могу только на поставленный вопрос. Ни больше, ни меньше.

Обратите внимание, что, возможно, вы выбрали далеко не самый оптимальный способ решения стоящей перед вами задачи. Предлагаю вам остановиться и обдумать все еще раз, прежде чем использовать это решение.

---

#### Решение после обновления вопроса

```
// Храните данные о результатах матча в массиве.
// Так вы сократите число переменных.
// Обратите внимание, что у меня очки целочисленные.
// Раз над ними будет проводиться операция сравнения, это логично.
$match = array(
    'home' => array(
        'name'  => 'Зайцы',
        'score' => 3
    ),
    'guest' => array(
        'name'  => 'ТрынТрава',
        'score' => 0
    )
);

// Эта функция возвращает случайный элемент массива.
// Замечания по работе штатной функции array_rand почитайте в документации:
// http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-rand.php
function array_random($array) {
    $random_key = mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1);

    return $array[$random_key];
}

// Эта функция возвращает текстовый результат сравнения очков команд
function analyze_score_difference($score_a, $score_b) {
    // Разница по очкам высчитывается по модулю
    $score_difference = abs($score_a - $score_b);

    // Разница равна 0? Команды сыграли вничью.
    if ($score_difference === 0) {
        return 'equal';
    }

    // Разница равна 1? Команды сыграли с минимальной разницей.
    if ($score_difference === 1) {
        return 'minimum-difference';
    }

    // Обычный матч
    return 'default';
}

// Функция возвращает случайное сообщение для результатов матча
function get_match_status_message($match) {
    $messages = array(
        // Ничья
        'equal' => array(
            // Прямой порядок Хозяин - Гость
            '%s дома сыграл вничью с %s',
            // Обратный порядок Гость - Хозяин
            '%2$s на выезде сыграл вничью с %1$s'
        ),
        // Минимальная разница
        'minimum-difference' => array(
            '%s дома с минимальным преимуществом переиграл %s',
            '%2$s на выезде минимально проиграл %1$s'
        ),
        // Обычный матч
        'default' => array(
            '%s дома переиграл %s',
            '%2$s на выезде проиграл %1$s'
        )
    );

    // Анализируем результаты матча
    $match_result = analyze_score_difference(
        $match['home']['score'],
        $match['guest']['score']
    );

    // Возвращаем случайное сообщение для результатов матча
    // Документация по sprintf
    // http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php
    // Обратите внимание на: "Пример #4 Изменение порядка параметров"
    return sprintf(
        array_random($messages[$match_result]),
        $match['home']['name'],
        $match['guest']['name']
    );
}

// Вывод результатов матча
echo get_match_status_message($match);
```

Обратите внимание, что здесь нет проверок переменных или существования ключей в массиве. В моем примере только самый основной функционал. Переделайте его под себя.

**[Посмотреть пример работы](http://ideone.com/UR1PCc)**

Comment: Не стоит рекомендовать того, чего не должно быть в приложении.

Comment: @romeo, где вы увидели "рекомендацию"? Я ответил на поставленный вопрос, сославшись на существующую статью в документации.

Comment: Вы опытный разработчик, а потому должны правильно оценить ситуацию. Или вы так боретесь с конкуренцией?

Comment: @romeo, извините, я не понимаю о какой конкуренции идет речь. Я признаю, что отчасти вы правы, но правы только в том, что мне следовало предупредить автора о том, что, возможно, он делает что-то не так. Я все же не вижу в формулировке своего ответа никаких рекомендаций, что, например, следует делать так и только так.

Comment: Если вы о словах перед ссылкой на документацию, так вот они относятся только к документации. Чтение документации полезно в любом случае, вы не находите?

Comment: `предупредить автора о том, что, возможно, он делает что-то не так` Да, в конце приведённого вами решения было бы уместно.

Comment: @romeo добавил соответствующее предупреждение для автора

Comment: Нет слов, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте вот так

```
$func = "func_".$rand;
echo $func();
```